# Localize jQuery Date Picker using the Zend Framework

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, localization, datepicker

I am trying to create a datepicker using a different locale than English. According to the jQuery manual I need to add the line:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

to `$view->jquery()->addOnLoad()`. The code is output and runs without any errors, but the month and day names are still in English.

Is there some simpler option or what am I overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm.. did you think of including the fr-localization-file on your page? Else it can't work.

Include this file after jQuery datepicker.

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js

Comment: No I used the 'i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js'. Using just your link for the specific language and throwing out the above code did the trick.